# My code keeps returning 'none' as a value, I am not sure why

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to complete a project from "automate the boring stuff" and whenever i run my code i keep getting none as a value.

I have tried to include return functions but then my whole while loop is ignored

```
tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'],
             ['Alice','Bob','Carol','David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(z):
    x = 0    
    while len(z)<3:
        print(z[x:len(z)])
        x+= 1
        if x > len(z):
            break
print(printTable(tableData))
```

Comment: Why did you think it *would* return something?

Comment: You need to return something from the function. Right now the function returns None and you print it

Comment: I do not see a return statement, if there is no return statement, `None` is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your While Loop is being ignored because len(z) is never less than 3 so you never enter the while loop. Also if you want your function to return something you must be explicit.

I changed len(z) to be greater or equal to 3 and I returned x. This should help you get back on track:

```
tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'],
             ['Alice','Bob','Carol','David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


def printTable(z):
    x = 0
    while len(z) <= 3:
        print(z[x:len(z)])
        x = x + 1
        if x > len(z):
            break
    return x


print(printTable(tableData))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know what to exactly return? Could you briefly describe your thought process when you returned x?

Comment: Since x was the value that changed based on the logic in the while loop it seemed like the best option in the code that was posted

Answer (score 2):

In Python, functions return `None` by default. So, the return value in your code will always be `None`.

Your `printTable` function should explicitly return a value; add a `return` of a value in an appropriate place.

You write:

> I have tried to include return functions but then my whole while loop is ignored

<sub>(I'm not familiar with the term "return function"; I'll assume you meant "return statement".)</sub>

That sounds like you have put the `return` in the wrong place -- inside the loop. Try putting it on the line after `break`, at the same level of indentation as the `while` statement. This will make sure that the return only happens once the loop has ended.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the `return` function outside of the loop.